# somthing wrong with run dev

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sass

hey guys i have a problem when i run npm run dev in laravel project for sass files to build i get this error:

```
> @gainhq/pipex@ dev D:\yarb yzb6
> mix


✖ Mix
  Compiled with some errors in 732.20ms

ERROR in /js/core
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\yarb yzb6\resources\js\mainApp.js' in 'D:\yarb yzb6'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]'?       

ERROR in /js/core
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\yarb yzb6\resources\sass\_global.scss' in 'D:\yarb yzb6'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]'?       

ERROR in /js/core
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\yarb yzb6\resources\sass\core\core.scss' in 'D:\yarb yzb6'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]'?       

webpack compiled with 3 errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @gainhq/pipex@ dev: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @gainhq/pipex@ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DRR8158\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-17T11_50_27_748Z-debug.log
```

i dont know why , and this my webpack.mix :

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const path = require('path');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.setPublicPath("public")
    .setResourceRoot("../") // Turns assets paths in css relative to css file
    // .options({
    //     processCssUrls: false,
    // })
    .sass("resources/sass/core/core.scss", "css/core.css")
    .sass("node_modules/dropzone/src/dropzone.scss", "css/dropzone.css")
    .sass("resources/sass/_global.scss", "css/fontawesome.css")
    .js("resources/js/mainApp.js", "js/core.js").vue()
    .extract([
        // Extract packages from node_modules to vendor.js
        "jquery",
        "bootstrap",
        "popper.js",
        "axios",
        "sweetalert2",
        "lodash"
    ])
    .sourceMaps();
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@app": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/crm/"),
            "@core": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/core/")
        }
    }
});
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version().options({
        // Optimize JS minification process
        terser: {}
    });
} else {
    // Uses inline source-maps on development
    mix.webpackConfig({
        devtool: "inline-source-map",
    });
}
```

tried to fix it with some methods like --force or to update webpack.mix but nothing work for me i tried to downgrade npm and node and nothing work for me for sure i dont know why this errors are show in

i tried to run it with --force but not works for me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a path related issue.

Try remove space from the folder "yarb yzb6" like this or something "yarb-yzb6"
Check if it solves the problem.

Check the detailed installation guide here: [Pipex Documentation](https://pipex.gainhq.com/documentation/developer-guide.html)

Comment: the same thing check this pic and i think there is somthing wrong [photo](https://ibb.co/FVzWd56) @Mushfiqur Mashuk